# ASP.NET Check Box Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, forms

I am creating a form in ASP.NET C# so it can be filled out and emailed to multiple recipients.  Part of the form is a checkbox section with multiple options.  I can only get the first option selected to be emailed back to the recipients, so if the user selects two or more checkboxes, it only emails the first option.  Below is my code sheet

```
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    MailAddress From = new MailAddress(mailTextBox.Text);
    message.To.Add(new MailAddress("email@domain.com"));
    message.Subject = (companyTextBox.Text);
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    message.Body = "<html><head></head><body>" +
    "<p></p>" +
    "<p>Business Type: " + typeDropDownList.Text + "</p>" +
    "<p>Company: " + companyTextBox.Text + "</p>" +
    "<p>Name: " + nameTextBox.Text + "</p>" +
    "<p>Address: " + addressTextBox.Text + "</p>" +
    "<p>City: " + cityTextBox.Text + "</p>" +
    "<p>State: " + stateDropDownList.Text + "</p>" +
    "<p>Zip Code: " + zipcodeTextBox.Text + "</p>" +
    "<p>Phone Number: " + phoneTextBox.Text + "</p>" +
    "<p>Email: " + mailTextBox.Text + "</p>" +
    "<p>Number Of Locations: " + locationsDropDownList.Text + "</p>" +

    **// This is my problem area //**
    "<p>Interested In: " + interestedCheckBoxList.Text + "</p>" +
    "<p>Interested In: " + interestedCheckBoxList.Text + "</p>" +
    "<p>Interested In: " + interestedCheckBoxList.Text + "</p>" +
    **// This is my problem area //**

    "<p>Message: " + messageTextBox.Text + "</p>" +
    "</body></html>";
    smtpClient.Send(message);
    Response.Redirect("http://www.domain.com");
```

Thank you in advance.

Jim

Comment: You're taking the same 3 lines of code and replicating it.

Comment: I would also recommend using StringBuilder.

Comment: Also, there is a difference between the CheckBox control and the CheckBoxList control in asp.net.  Be careful not to get them confused.

Comment: I know.  I had one there, so I just added the others to see if would do anything different.  But it emails the first option three times.  What I figured what it would do.  I need option 2, 3, 4 etc.

Comment: Look at the three lines? What is the difference between them? Nothing, that is why you see the same thing three times.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to loop through the Items in the CheckBoxList and add them individually.

Example:

```
foreach(ListItem li in interestedCheckBoxList.Items)
{
   //add your stuff
   if(li.Selected)
   {
       //should be using string builder here but....
       message.Body += "<p>Interested In: " + li.Text + "</p>";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through your CheckBoxList and find all the checked items and get the `Text` property for each item and append to you email text.

```
string yourSelectedList = "";
foreach (ListItem i in chklst.Items)
{
    if (i.Selected)
         yourSelectedList += (i.Text + ", ");
}
```

Then remove the extra comma at the end :)

```
"<p>Interested In: " + yourSelectedList  + "</p>" +
```

Try to use `StringBuilder` when concatentating many strings together as it will make a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the code in your "problem area" with the following:

```
string InterestedIn = "";
foreach (ListItem li in interestedCheckBoxList.Items)
{
    if (li.Selected)
        InterestedIn += "<p>Interested In: " + li.Text + "</p>";
}
```

Of course, you can't concatenate this as part of your original string concatenation, so build an "InterestedIn" string of sorts and concatenate the email body with that.